# Python Nameerror after importing file

Tags: import, python-3.3, nameerror

I'm learning python 3.3 for the first time and in the tutorial I have to do my own module and import them. The problem here is that even if the import worked, I get an nameerror depending of the method I use to import it. Well here are the 2 codes for import:

```
from package.fonctions import table
table(5) # Appel de la fonction table

# Ou ...
import package.fonctions
fonctions.table(5) # Appel de la fonction table
```

Here is the code it is supposed to call:

```
def table(nb, max=10):
    """Fonction affichant la table de multiplication par nb de
    1 * nb jusqu'à max * nb"""
    i = 0
    while i < max:
        print(i + 1, "*", nb, "=", (i + 1) * nb)
        i += 1
```

The first import method work, but not the second. It tells me that the name "fonctions" is not defined, but the import worked and the first method worked too.

In the tutorial, both method work, but for me it doesn't even if I just copy-paste the code. I just want to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

`import package.fonctions` doesn't define `fonctions` name. It enables to call `package.fonctions.table(5)` instead.

To enable `fonctions.table(5)`, use `from package import fonctions`.